# Python : Merge 2 Dataframes based on first substring match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with values that need to be merged.

DF1:

| Summary | Occurences |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa az123-12-12 is not working | 2 |
| cdxd ab0sg1-mtht and az123-12-12is not working | 3 |
| cdxd ab222sg1-mtht and az124-12 is not working | 3 |

DF2 :

| Keywords | Group |
| --- | --- |
| az123-12-12 | row |
| ab0sg1-mtht | row |

I want it to merge based on the first Keyword from DF2 encountered in DF1's Summary.

Desired Output :

| Summary | Occurences | Keywords | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa az123-12-12 is not working | 2 | az123-12-12 | row |
| cdxd ab0sg1-mtht and az123-12-12is not working | 3 | ab0sg1-mtht | row |
| cdxd ab222sg1-mtht and az124-12 is not working | 3 |  |  |

Code #1

```
DF1['Keywords'] = ''
for val in DF2.Keywords:
    DF1.loc[DF1['Summary'].str.match(val), 'Keywords'] = val
```

This only works on some cases and doesnt work for another, I need help with identifying a better and efficient way to get the desired output.
Note : Keywords might have "-" character in them which also needs to work.

Thanks in advance.

Code #2

```
DF1['aux'] = DF1['Summary'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[1]

pd.merge_ordered(DF1, DF2, right_on='Keywords', left_on='aux',
         how='outer').drop('aux', axis=1)
```

This is the output being produced:

| Summary | Occurences | Keywords | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa az123-12-12 is not working | 2 | az123-12-12 | row |
| cdxd ab0sg1-mtht and az123-12-12is not working | 3 | ab0sg1-mtht | row |
| cdxd ab222sg1-mtht and az124-12 is not working | 3 | - | row |

Comment: Why the 2nd row in DF1 does not also match with "az123-12-12"?

Comment: Thats one of the things- I only need it to match with the first substring and not the second since it takes precedence.

Comment: Ah okay. I saw you mentioned "first Keyword".  my bad.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# to extract from Summary the key to use with pd.merge
df1['aux'] = df1['Summary'].str.split(expand=True)[1]

pd.merge(df1, df2, right_on='Keywords', left_on='aux',
         how='outer').drop('aux', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                                         Summary  Occurences     Keywords  \
0                 aaaa az123-12-12 is not working           2  az123-12-12   
1  cdxd ab0sg1-mtht and az123-12-12is not working           3  ab0sg1-mtht   
2  cdxd ab222sg1-mtht and az124-12 is not working           3          NaN   

  Group  
0   row  
1   row  
2   NaN
```

Comment: This doesnt match the exact keywords exactly. It is matching a even a special character from df2 from keyword if it exists in df1.

Comment: But it did pick up some other ones that my code could not pick up. So definitely appreciate that. Can it be corrected so it matches exact keywords to substring in summary?

Comment: Do not you want to match  *always* the second substring in `Summary` column of `df1`?

Comment: Look: the `aux`column that I add to `df1` has this content: `0      az123-12-12
1      ab0sg1-mtht
2    ab222sg1-mtht
Name: aux, dtype: object`.

Comment: I want to match always the first.

Comment: What happens for me in a bigger and actual database is that it also goes on to match a "-" character from the keywords to the summary. It went on to match " for " from Keyword- A for B to any other for that exists in the summary. I want it to match the exact keyword to a substring in summary

Comment: Do you mean that when trying to match keyword `az123-12-12`, you *only* want to match `az123`?

Comment: I mean i need to match "az123-12-12" exactly to a string in summary. Cant match any single characters.

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding correctly what you want, but, if my guess is correct, you just need to replace `merge` by `merge_ordered` in my code.

Comment: In case my suggestion does not work, I would suggest you to editing your question, indicating, with examples, where my code does not produce the output you want.

Comment: I will add it to the question.

Comment: Mentioned it under Code #2.

Comment: I have just run code #2 on my computer and I do not get the output you report, but the output you desire! So, it appears the problem is on your side.